# absolute Indoor Positioning with cache data

Tags: android, ios, indoor-positioning-system

My project is an AR project needs to get user's position in a booth/room. The acceptable error is probably ~10 cm. As the users are going to use our device, so it does't matter if it's apple or android. And we can do any set up before use. And if it's need, we can add external device.

In the beginning, i was thinking about ARKit. But ARkit only gives you the relative position based on the start position, i need the absolute position based the room. I thought about iBeacon, but the error seems to large for a meeting room size place. I took a look on Structure Sensor. I knew they can export a scanned 3d model, but i don't feel they can save/load the point cloud for tracking.

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0):

Occipital's Structure Sensor can be used for 6-DoF inside-out positional tracking within your error specifications using the Structure SDK and Bridge Engine. https://structure.io/developers and https://bridge.occipital.com/developers have more information.

If you are making a device, Occipital also has an embedded solution, Structure Core: https://structure.io/core, as well as tracking that can rely solely on camera and IMU data: https://occipital.com/tracking